# Troubleshoot invalid rows in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sed, large-data

I am working with a very large CSV file (nearly 6 gigabytes), and it is absolutely riddled with errors. For example, if I have the following csv file/table:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+
|     ID     |    Date     |   String   |
+------------+-------------+------------+
|  123456    |  09-20-2019 |   ABCDEFG  |
|  123abc456 |  10-30-2019 |   HIJKLMN  |
|  7891011   |  jdqhouehwf |   OPQRSTU  |
|  1010101   |  03-15-2018 |   8473737  |
|  4823.00   |  02-11-2015 |   VWXYZ    |
|  2348813.0 |  01-23-2016 |   BAZ      |
+------------+-------------+------------+
```

or:

```
"ID","Date","String"
123456,"09-20-2019","ABCDEFG"
123abc456,"10-30-2019","HIJKLMN"
7891011,"jdqhouehwf","OPQRSTU"
1010101,"03-15-2018",8473737
4823.00,"02-11-2015","VWXYZ"
"2348813.0","01-23-2016","BAZ"
```

I want a good way to troubleshoot and fix the file. Using pandas, I can read in the file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(inputfile)
```

Pandas will invariably complain along the lines of:
`sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (0) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False`

So I want to clean up each column. But since it is a very large file, I can't just print my entire table to output with masking and expect to read it. I want an easy way to take a column and check if it conforms to a type. Also, I want a way to remove bad rows and/or convert rows into the correct format, if possible. After all is said and done, I want the file to look like (not including inline comments):

```
"ID","Date","String"
123456,"09-20-2019","ABCDEFG"
#  123abc456,"10-30-2019","HIJKLMN" was deleted because the ID wasn't a number
#  7891011,"jdqhouehwf","OPQRSTU" was deleted because the data was not a date
1010101,"03-15-2018","8473737" # The last number could be converted to string
4823,"02-11-2015","VWXYZ" # The first number could be converted to integer
2348813,"01-23-2016","BAZ" # The ID number could be converted to int
```

Comment: Pre-process it line-by-line with the csv module and write the corrected/valid rows/lines to a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def main():

    from pathlib import Path
    import csv
    import datetime as dt

    with Path("thing.csv").open("r") as file:
        for row in csv.DictReader(file):
            try:
                row["ID"] = int(float(row["ID"]))
                row["Date"] = dt.datetime.strptime(row["Date"], "%m-%d-%Y")
            except (KeyError, ValueError):
                continue
            print(*row.values())

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged `sed`, here's a command that should do the job in a pretty much efficient and portable way, but it is a bit unreadable...

```
sed -n '1p;s/^"\{0,1\}\([0-9]\+\)\(\.[0-9]*\)\{0,1\}"\{0,1\}\(,"\(0[0-9]\|1[0-2]\)-\([0-2][0-9]\|3[01]\)-2[0-9]\{3\}",\)"\{0,1\}\([^"]*\)"\{0,1\}$/\1\3"\6"/p' file
```

What it does is:

1. print the header, i.e. the first line (`1p`),
2. try a substitute (`s`) command on all lines and print the result only if the substitution succeeded (and hence only if the line matched the search pattern) `s/…/…/p`.

As regards the substitute pattern `\1\3"\6"`, each escaped number refers to the correspoding captured group (`\(…\)`; remember that the groups are assigned a number based on the order with which the opening `\(` tokens appear). Specifically:

1. `\1` refers leading number (`[0-9]\+`), with or without (`\{0,1\}`) the following three things:

   - the leading `"`,
   - the trailing decimal part `\.[0-9]*`,
   - and the following `"`;
2. `\3` refers to the date, surrounding `"` included (`"\(0[0-9]\|1[0-2]\)-\([0-2][0-9]\|3[01]\)-2[0-9]\{3\}"`, *note that I've been inaccurate in this regex, as it will also match non-existing dates, like the 31st of February*);
3. `"\6"` refers (and put it in between `"`) to the final alphanumeric string, on which I made almost no assumptions (`[^"]*`).

This should match the dates a bit better (except that the 29th of February is always matched, regardless of the year):

```
sed -n '1p;s/^"\{0,1\}\([0-9]\+\)\(\.[0-9]*\)\{0,1\}"\{0,1\}\(,"\(\(0[0-9]\|1[0-2]\)-[0-2][0-9]\|\(0[469]\|11\)-30\|\(0[13578]\|1[02]\)-31\)-2[0-9]\{3\}",\)"\{0,1\}\([^"]*\)"\{0,1\}$/\1\3"\8"/p' file
```

Comment: This is great for weeding out bad entries, but it won't handle conversions if possible. Ideally, deleting a row would only be done as a last resort.

Comment: @GeoffreySaunders, converting what? A CSV file is a text file, isn't it? In your comments to the code it seems to me that you use _convert to int_ to refer to the removal of `"` and the decimal part.